# Swift UI Testing with Kif

Tags: xcode, swift, kif

I am working on UI testing in Xcode using Swift and the Kif framework. My question is about AccessibilityLabels. The accessibility labels are dynamic and change, is there a way to use different labels that are static to identify buttons and other actions that take place?

For Example:

```
 tester().tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel("Apr 29, 2015")
```

Where `"Apr 29, 2015"` is the accessibility label but it changes every day. What other label or identifier can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use accessibilityIdentifier. Identifier should be unique. Import KIF/IdentifierTests

Comment: That is what we started using. That is a much better way to do it. Thanks.